# The property of being fixed-point free and having no retraction are equivalent.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I came across this problem in an old qualifier exam that I haven't been able to solve yet.  It states that the following two statements are equivalent:

1) There is no retraction $\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

2) Every continuous map $\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n$ has a fixed point.

Proving that $(1) \implies (2)$ is relatively straight forward, creating a retraction from a fixed point free map.  However, I'm having difficulties proving $(2) \implies (1)$.  My guess was to assume that there is a retraction and construct a map without a fixed point, but I haven't got very far with this.

Comment: Does "retraction" include $r\lvert_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer - Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a retraction must leave $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ pointwise fixed, we get a quick proof of $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ via the contrapositive.

If $r \colon \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is a retraction, then $\nu \circ r$ is a fixed-point free map $\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{D}^n$, where $\nu(x) = -x$ is the antipodal map. $\nu \circ r$ can have no fixed point in the interior of $\mathbb{D}^n$, since its image is contained in the sphere, and it has no fixed point on the boundary, since there it is the antipodal map.

Comment: :) haha, thanks.